# ASP.NET Webservice Marshal.Copy Security exception

Tags: .net, web-services, exception

I am attempting to make a webservice, one of the functions of which is image editing. In one method that works with a bitmap, I need to call Marshal.Copy(...), however seemingly at that point I get this exception:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I have no idea how to get around this, and Google proved to be of little help. I say "seemingly at that point" because I can't properly debug, since the stack does not include the actual method where the exception occurred, just the general method that works with the bitmap, and that seems like the most likely thing to throw it.

To add some context, my goal here is to get the pixel data out of a bitmap, and put it in  a byte array.

Any help in either an alternative method to get pixel data in byte array form from a bitmap or a way to get around that security exception would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not running the service in `fulltrust`.

Comment: I'm not running the service on a local server. The server is not mine, thus I can't set the trust level.

Comment: Find a host that can do that.

Comment: I'm not currently in a position to do that. I'm looking for a programmatic solution or workaround here.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no workaround. I too needed a `fulltrust` host to run IronScheme on it. If you want a cheap one, I can suggest Arvixe.